# How to push notify consumers from kafka message bus

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am writing microservice application using C# asp.net core 2.0, Kafka, CQRS and Confluent Kafka .net library.

Just wonder if kafka can notify the consumers rather than the consumers poll/consume message?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, by pushing a message onto the message bus which gets polled/consumed by the consumers. What exactly is the question or problem you have?

Answer (score 3):

Kafka can not push notifications to consumers.

Consumers have to keep polling/consuming messages in order to receive them. This is the only way messages stored in Kafka can flow to consumers.

The [Consumer Design section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_pull) in the Apache Kafka documentation explains why "consumer pulling" was choosed over "broker pushing".

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is pull only, that's by design. But you could use an higher level abstraction. I've built a library called Silverback (https://github.com/BEagle1984/silverback) that implements all that for you, so that you can focus on the logic. The consume loop is implemented in Silverback, that then "pushes" the messages to your subscribers.

See a sample here: https://silverback-messaging.net/samples/kafka/basic.html#consumer.